# What are Node.JS's getHiddenValue and setHiddenValue functions, which wrap V8's GetPrivate and SetPrivate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

For very complicated reasons, I'm researching to better understand the internals of Node.JS, and have discovered two functions of unknown purpose.

These are the functions and how to access them.

```
process.binding('util').setHiddenValue
process.binding('util').getHiddenValue
```

From [their native code declarations](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ce7d3077dc990ca5a627bd83894712f586ca16f1/src/node_util.cc#L68-L100), it's clear they wrap the following V8 functions:

```
v8::Object::SetPrivate
v8::Object::GetPrivate
```

I've also made a little snippet that kind-of shows what they can do.

```
'use strict';

var binding = process.binding('util');

var o = {};

binding.setHiddenValue(o, 7, 'testing123');

console.log(binding.getHiddenValue(o, 7)); // returns 'testing123'
```

However, I've been unable to find any documentation on what these so-called "hidden values" are for, or otherwise determine why they are needed in Node or in V8.

Can anyone shed some light on their true purpose?

For reference, these appears to be the only valid values you can use to associate the data by (higher than 7 will crash):

```
alpn_buffer_private_symbol: 0,
arrow_message_private_symbol: 1,
contextify_context_private_symbol: 2,
contextify_global_private_symbol: 3,
decorated_private_symbol: 4,
npn_buffer_private_symbol: 5,
processed_private_symbol: 6,
selected_npn_buffer_private_symbol: 7,
```

Comment: As they're undocumented, using them is an extremely bad idea, surely? :-) They could change from one dot release to the next.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand this. My purposes are very unusual. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-3.0/db/d85/classv8_1_1_object.html#a98ad2e2a82b457a733bee13e4c2ba876 :

> Access hidden properties on JavaScript objects. These properties are hidden from the executing JavaScript and only accessible through the V8 C++ API. Hidden properties introduced by V8 internally (for example the identity hash) are prefixed with "v8::".

However, they will not be used in v7 and beyond -- https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/924cc6c6335e58f61b04d2f41d348bd6b8be98a1

To compare with vanilla JS:

```
const foo = Object.create({}, {
  privBar: {value: 'private'},
  publBar: {value: 'public', enumerable: true}
})

console.log(foo.privBar) // 'private'
console.log(foo.publBar) // 'public'
```

Notice that we can still access `privBar` because it isn't really private. But if we `JSON.stringify(foo)` then only `publBar` will show up in the serialization. With the v8 functions you get an even more private `privBar`.

Comment: Nice find! Any indication what exactly they are actually used for though (I've added the constant names that are used to the question)? Also, I'm using node version v7.2.1, so I'm not sure about v7 removing them?

Comment: My answer was when you were asking about `Set/GetHiddenValue`. That v7 commit makes the switch to `Set/GetPrivate`. Either way, they should be the same thing; the newer pair just being the preferred updated code. As for what they're used for, I assume for things that Node really wants to keep private.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I would have guessed they were internal to V8, as they seem to be set by V8 code, but it does look like they are all defined in Node-land. I think the closest thing in pure-JS would be a `WeakMap`.